# Script returns NaN in Apple's Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari, nan

So the script workis just fine in Chrome, but in Safari on MacOS it returns NaN instead of the value, just like in Chrome.

```
setInterval(function() {
    var distance = Date.parse(2018-07-30 20:20:20) - new Date().getTime(),
        days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
        hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)),
        minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)),
        seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    $(".timer").html(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");
}, 1000);
```

In Chrome result looks like for example: 0d 22h 15m 27s

In Safari result looks like: NaNd NaNh NaNm NaNs

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact script you're running? `Date.parse(2018-07-30 20:20:20)` is missing quotation marks, and will throw a syntax error on most browsers (causing no code to run at all).

Comment: In my code I've got jQuery function which get's the value of the div, but just in this case I added the value manually, and yea the script runs in both Safari and Chrome.

Comment: Then include that part of your code.

Comment: Not sure what will it change, as if You'd like to check the code in Pen or whatever it wouldn't help at all, but as wished - Date.parse($(".time-left").html()) - that's how it looks.

Comment: In Chrome's console it returns: 1529682812000, but in Safari console it returns: NaN... Looks like Date.parse works different in Chrome and Safari.